# Zabbix API to get the details of traffic used by the applications

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api

I would like to get the details/usage of network traffic used by each application (not by host).

I tried and I was able to get the list of application running on a host, by using:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "application.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend",
        "hostids": "10107"
    },
    "auth": "02axxxxxxx6e1023exxx252cd2xx70",
    "id": 1
}
```

but I need the network traffic consumption details:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native way to do it.

The `application.get` api retrieves the application list from the template/host, Zabbix uses it as a grouping mechanism.

See Configuration -> Templates -> Pick one -> Applications